# Database connection error after upgrading Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I encountered a weird database error after I upgraded my wordpress from version 3.5 to the latest version, I believe it is version 4.3.
So after I updated my wordpress, my site start to shows error message "Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" even though the database user has been granted all permission. I am also unable to access the wp-admin.

Is there anyway I could fixed this problem, or should I asked my server provider to re-roll the database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the database data in the wp-config.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your mysql databases password and update that new password in your wp-config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies guys, but apparently there's nothing wrong with the configs. I found out that one of my wordpress plugin is causing the problem, after I deleted it through ftp, my wordpress site is back online again!